# Show that $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

how can I prove that $$ \mathbb Q [x] / (x ^ 2-2)$$ is a field. I tried but as I'm starting on this subject I'm still not very good, I'm still learning. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is isomorphic to $Q[\sqrt{2}]$ which is a field and you can show every $a+\sqrt{2}b\in Q[\sqrt{2}]$ invertible for $a,b\in Q$. Consider the morphism $Q[x]\to Q[\sqrt{2}]$ by sending $x$ to $\sqrt{2}$. Show the kernel is $x^2-2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-2)$ is a field iff $X^2-2$ is a maximal ideal.in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a principal ideal domain (X^2-2) is a maximal ideal iff X^2-2 is irreduicible. And $X^2-2$ is irreduicible.

Answer (score 1):

With $x = \sqrt{2}$ in mind, we find the useful identity $$(a+b x)(a-bx) = a^2 -
 b^2 x^2 \equiv a^2 - 2b^2 \bmod (x^2-2)$$
So that in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ : 
$$\frac{1}{a+bx} = \frac{a-bx}{a^2-2b^2}$$

Comment: One needs to be sure that $a^2-2b^2\ne0$ here.